# If String's beginning inc spec Values

Tags: c++, if-statement

I'm trying to write a program that checks 15-16 digit inputs and see what bank they belong to. I'm not familiar with the language I'm coding in(c++), and would like some pointers. I know you can't copy and paste without the rest of the code, but it would be to long to post all of it. I just need a little adivce on a couple things.

Right now I have the program checking the length of the input and what the first two values of the string are. I would like to know if there is an easier way then what I have right now.

```
if(cLen==15 && c[0]== 3 && c[1]==4)
```

and

```
if(cLen==15 && c[0]== 3 && c[1]==7)
```

cause all I need is to find Strings that have the first two nums to be 34 or 37

secondly I need to check if the string has first values of 51 through 55

and lastly I need to check if the string contains 6011 at the beginning.

```
string validatebankcc(string c, int cLen, bool& ccOK) {
    string bankcc;
    if(cLen==15 && c[0]== 3 && c[1]==4)
        bankcc = "AmericanExpress";
    if(cLen==15 && c[0]== 3 && c[1]==7)
        bankcc = "AmericanExpress";
    if(cLen==16 && "6011 in beginning")
        bankcc = "Discover";
    if(cLen==16 && c[0]==5 && c[1]==1)
        bankcc="MasterCard";
    if(cLen==16 && c[0]==5 && c[1]==5)
        bankcc="MasterCard";
    if(c[0]==4)
        bankcc="Visa";
    else
        bankcc = "Uknown Bank"
    return bankcc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool got_length_and_prefix(string s, int desired_length, string desired_prefix) {
  if (s.length() != desired_length) return false;
  if (s.find(desired_prefix) != 0) return false;
  return true;
}

string validatebankcc(string c, int /* cLen useless here*/, bool& ccOK) {
  ccOK = true;

  if (got_length_and_prefix(c, 15, "34")) return "AmericanExpress";
  if (got_length_and_prefix(c, 15, "37")) return "AmericanExpress";
  if (got_length_and_prefix(c, 16, "6011")) return "Discover";
  if (got_length_and_prefix(c, 16, "51")) return "MasterCard";
  if (got_length_and_prefix(c, 16, "55")) return "MasterCard";
  if (c[0] == '4') return "Visa";

  ccOK = false;
  return "Unkown Bank";
}
```

Though overall design is bad. Returning bank name as string is crying for trouble (which also leads to useless ccOK flag, which can be replaced by BANK_UNKNOWN or smth like that. Passing string length along with string which known about it length also smells like trouble.

Comment: I don't know about the "smell" issue, but I agree mostly with this answer.  I think the method should return an enum, whose first value is unknown_bank (or whatever), which means you can treat the return value of this function as a bool (the first value of an enum defaults to zero unless you make it be some other value).

Comment: `find_first_of` finds any of the characters in the search filter you give it. Use `find` instead. It might be faster to take a substring of the first `desired_prefix.size()` characters instead of checking the entire string.

Comment: also, that logic states that "42" is valid visa card number which is awesome but, unfortunately, not true.

Comment: @iced, You'd still keep the length check. It was just a thought for a replacement of looping through the entire string. For strings this short, it would really not even matter, though.

Comment: @chris string::length doesn't loop through string, it keeps length pre-calculated (and in any case, as you stated, this is useless for such short string).

Comment: oh ;) but yes, it really doesn't matter

Comment: This is almost perfect with the exception I need values 51-55

Comment: @iced, I just realized that constructing one would have to loop through to fill the characters in. D'oh.

Comment: copypaste that line 3 more times. I mean it - it's ok for such cases, no need to add complexity. in good language (aka lisp) you can sneak in some simple dsl there with the same amount of code, but for c++ stick with copypaste.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (c.find("6011") != string::npos && c.find("6011") == 0) //"6011" in beginning
{
}
```

Comment: The first check is redundant. If it's equal to 0, it won't be equal to `std::string::npos`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need to pass around the string length - there is a member function `size()` for that. Secondly, you should be passing by `const &`. Finally, you can use `find_first_of` to simplify this:

Hence your method will look something like this:

```
string validate_bank_cc(const string& c, bool& ccOk) 
{
    if((c.size() == 15) && (c.find_first_of("34") == 0))
        return "AmericanExpress";
    //etc...
}
```